# Using value in drop down menu to search sql database

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu, search-engine

I'm new with php and want to ask about this code.. I have one dropdown menu and one button..
I want to search in sql database what I choose in those drop down menu..
What is the sql syntax for search item in sql database by using drop down menu..
By default, I write --> `SELECT * FROM helpline`.

It should be --> `SELECT * FROM helpline WHERE MISC = %**item in drop down menu**%`.

This is my database = helpdesk

```
Table = helpline

NAME  |    DATE    |  MISC  |
John  | 02/01/2011 | Item 1 |
Mark  | 03/01/2011 | Item 2 |
```

This is my code

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
<label for="namelist"></label>
<select name="namelist" id="namelist">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">PLEASE CHOOSE ONE ITEM:-</option>
<option>Item 1</option>
<option>Item 2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="show" id="show" value="Submit" />
<?php
mysql_select_db("helpdesk",mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))or die (mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM helpline"; */ This line should select what I choose in drop down menu  /*
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="6" class="curve">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> <div align="right"><span class="font">NAME</span></div></th>
<th> <div align="right"><span class="font">DATE</span></div></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>   
<tr>
<th><div align="left"><span class="font"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span></div></th>
<td><div align="left"><span class="font"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></strong></span></div></td>   
</tr>
</tbody>
&nbsp;
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

So, it should display all items in sql database according to what I choose in drop down menu when I click the button..

Comment: Please. Stop. Using. `mysql_`. functions.

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to load that data without the page reloading, that the approperiate way to go would be to use ajax and I would recommend using a framework, cause ajax alone can be tricky for the unfamiliar eye. A good start would be using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can access your posted form data through the php `$_POST[]` associative array as described in [PHP's Online Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). From this you can select `namelist` and pass the value to your SQL.

---

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM helpline";
if(isset($_POST['namelist'])){
   $dropdown_val = $_POST['namelist'];
   $query .= " WHERE MISC = '$dropdown_val'"; 
}
```

---

But you should really be using ajax for this and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would be a great javascript framework to help you accomplish this. Also, mysql_*  functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Without Page Refresh You can do it like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#namelist").change(function(){
            var data = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:'search_value='+data,
                url:'search_process.php',
                success:function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }               
            });         
        }); 

    });


</script>
```

The HTML part

```
<select name="namelist" id="namelist">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">PLEASE CHOOSE ONE ITEM:-</option>
<option>Item 1</option>
<option>Item 2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="show" id="show" value="Submit" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

The search_process.php Page

```
<?php

 // DATABASE CONNECTIVITY

 if(isset($_POST['search_value'])) {
    $val = $_POST['search_value'];


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM helpline WHERE MISC LIKE %$val%");

    // NOW RUN YOUR QUERY

    $result = '<table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="6" class="curve">';
    $result .= '<thead>';
    $result .= '<tr>';
    $result .= '<th> <div align="right"><span class="font">NAME</span></div></th>';
    $result .= '<th> <div align="right"><span class="font">DATE</span></div></th>';
    $result .= '</tr>';
    $result .= '</thead>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $result .= '<tr>';
    $result .= '<th><div align="left"><span class="font">'.$row['name'].'</span></div></th>';
    $result .= '<td><div align="left"><span class="font">'.$row['date'].'</strong></span></div></td>'; 
    $result .= '</tr>';

}
    $result .= '</table>';
    echo $result;
 }
?>
```

Hope this gives an Idea

Answer (score 1):

your select options not have value attribute

```
your dropdown
<select name="namelist" id="namelist">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">PLEASE CHOOSE ONE ITEM:-</option>
<option>Item 1</option>
<option>Item 2</option>
</select>

change it :
<select name="namelist" id="namelist">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">PLEASE CHOOSE ONE ITEM:-</option>
<option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
<option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

after submit get value from $_post["namelist"]